# Was that actually the recipe for concentrated dark matter?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In the tv show Rick and Morty, there is a group of Aliens that are trying to scam Rick out of his recipe for a fuel that he invented to travel through space faster than anybody else called "concentrated dark matter". They trap Rick in a life-like simulation, and eventually he tells Morty to make some concentrated dark matter by mixing together two parts Plutonic Quarks, one part Cesium and a bottled water.

Since the aliens have what they want, they let Rick and his family go back to Earth, and use the recipe that they learned from Rick in the simulation, mixing the concoction together in a bucket which creates a gigantic explosion that blows them all up.

For an explosion of that size, it makes you wonder what they actually ended up making in that bucket. Was it concentrated dark matter?

Comment: I find it hard to believe Rick would ever give them what they want. He fooled them and probably gave them the recipe for a bomb.

Comment: @Walt I believe that Rick knew he was in a simulation and wasn't actually tricked because otherwise he would have stopped Morty from mixing the stuff on the dashboard, but I think there's still the possibility for some [be careful what you wish for](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeCarefulWhatYouWishFor) irony by giving them the recipe for something that he knows they can't control.

Comment: Sure, I just assume it based on his character. I don't think this was ever answered in the show.

Answer (score 16):

If you put cesium in water, it explodes. Google "cesium in water" to find plenty of videos about it. The point being that, it is known that cesium+water=explosion. Being a scientist, Rick knew this.

When he is telling Morty the ingredients, and then Morty immediately finds them all, Rick says (sarcastically) "Wow Morty, lucky break," as if he is not at all surprised that they just happened to have these things on hand and that Morty was able to locate them so quickly.

So we can infer at this point that Rick has been aware he is still in a simulation and gathers the ingredients to make an explosion.

I don't know what the "plutonic quarks" are for though...

Comment: I would assume that the plutonic quarks are a red herring to make the recipe seem more complicated than it actually is, and prevent the aliens from catching on to Rick's ploy.

Answer (score 2):

The recipe Rick gave was not actually for concentrated dark matter and was never intended to be.

Concerning the recipe:

Caesium is element number 55 on the periodic table of elements. It is an alkali metal which means it reacts violently in the presence of O<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>O, and because it is further down the list it reacts more violently than potassium or sodium.

“Plutonic quarks” is an oxymoron, being that “plutonic” basically means that molecular compounds have been condensed together by immense pressure, whereas quarks are particles that make up the protons and neutrons in the nucleus and would not be affected by the compression of molecular compounds. “Plutonic quartz” however is a more plausible statement regarding the recipe in that quartz is SiO2. Si, or silicon is not reactive in itself, but with two added oxygen atoms it has a positive charge on the end of the compound containing the oxygen atoms.

So, caesium and quartz alone would not react, but add the water and some of the hydrogen molecules in H2O, having a tendency to hold a negative charge, would possibly abandon their single Oxygen atom in the presence of caesium for the other oxygen atoms attached to the silicon making more oxygen available to combust with the caesium causing the grand explosion that Rick intended.

Answer (score -3):

I'm no scientist. But i'm guessing as they are 'Plutonic' (which i'm guessing has something to do with plutonium) quarks, then the heat from the reaction with the cesium did something and it became a sort of nuclear reaction. Well i'm guessing as it is a large explosion for only 1:1 of the cesium and water..